# Converting C++ to Assembly Language

Tags: c++, assembly

Implement the following C++ code in assembly language, using the block-structured .IF and .WHILE directives. Assume that all variables are 32-bit signed integers:

```
int array[] = {10,60,20,33,72,89,45,65,72,18}; 
int sample = 50;

int ArraySize = sizeof array / sizeof sample; 
int index = 0; int sum = 0; 
while( index < ArraySize ) 
{ 
  if( array[index] <= sample ) 
  { 
    sum += array[index]; 
  } 
  index++;
}
```

I have no idea how to do this.

This is what I know.

```
.WHILE index<ArraySize

.IF array(NO CLUE HOW TO DO INDEX ON ASEMBLY) <= sample
sum +=array(AGAIN NO IDEA)
.ENDIF
inc index
.ENDW
```

I really am trying I am just so confused. Also, this is an online course from Coursera so no, you're not doing my homework for me and I do pay attention. I am just struggling.

Comment: is this a homework assignment? What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Shoulda paid attention in class then before they handed out this assignment...

Comment: @ElGavilan It's not for a lecture actual class..

Comment: Compile and view the assembly..?

Comment: Since assembly language is processor dependent, what is your target processor?

Answer (score 2):

Look up your compiler documentation.  Most compilers and IDEs can eith produce assembly language files, listing or display code in assembly language.

Some compilers may produce a listing file where the assembly language is interwoven with C++ language statements.

**Edit 1: Manual assembly langauge**

**Indexing arrays**
Indexing an array is highly platform specific, or I shall say that different processors have different optimized methods for accessing an array element.

In the ARM7 processor, the address of the array is loading into a register and the offset into another register:

```
LDR R0, #Array  ; Load R0 with the address of the array.
MOV R1, #3      ; Load R1 with the offset, in this case, the 4th element.
LDR R2, R0[R1]  ; Load R2 with the value of Array[3].
```

This assumes you have an array of 32-bit values.

Another method is to add in the offset to the array register.  Remember that the offset value must be in units of byte. So the C++ equivalent is `*(Array + 3 * sizeof(int))` :

```
  LDR R0, #Array;
  MOV R1, #3
  MUL R1, R1, 4; Multiply by size of an int (4 bytes)
  ADD R0, R0, R1; Add R0 to R1 and place sum in R0.
  LDR R2, [R0]; Load value from address in R0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the .if .else .elseif .endif refer to directives used by masm 6.11 or later (actually ml.exe) for X86. I'll also assume it's 32 bit mode since 32 bit values are being used.

The .if directive needs the same type of operands as a compare instruction, so one of the operands needs to be a register and the other operand needs to be a memory reference, an immediate value, or a register, like this:

```
        .if     eax <= array[ebx]
        ; ...
        .else
        ; ...
        .endif
```

Microsoft reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4x287ff.aspx